# Can I use percentage units for box shadow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

That's it :), Is there a way to make a box shadow in css with percentage units? I'd like if it were with pure css. But if you guys think js is the only way, please let me know how...

Comment: Why would you need this? You can't do this with CSS because how would the percentage be arbitrarily calculated? If you provide an example use case, then a JavaScript solution could be written for that situation.

Comment: According to [the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow), you can't use percentages in box-shadow. And it doesn't get more authoritative than that, so, that's the final word. Use JS.